# WebView too long. Android

Tags: android, html, css, webview, scrollview

I have WebView, put it in to scrollview. I need to do it that way cause at the bottom 
I got ImageView and lower button.

The problem appear on Android 4.03. Where webview is much longer that it should be.

```
    WebView mWebView = null;
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.clearCache(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    mWebView.loadUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);    
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            acceptBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

    });
```

and the xml:

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_below="@+id/top"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helpText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/termsText"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/helpText"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/box_top" />      

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topTerms1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: "I have WebView, put it in to scrollview" -- That will not work reliably. Please remove the `ScrollView`. "I need to do it that way cause at the bottom I got ImageView and lower button." -- there is no `Button` in your layout. Note that StackOverflow is for questions, and you did not ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. ImageView behind the webview was too long because it wasn't ready to display webview.

Right now I setup the main view, load the page and then add the webview to main view.
The problem was not only on the ice scream sandwich, but on all platforms.